# Default value to non initialized variables

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I'm reading [this tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/) about debugging. I pasted the factorial code in my .c archive:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, num, j;
    printf ("Enter the number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num );

    for (i=1; i<num; i++)
        j=j*i;    

    printf("The factorial of %d is %d\n",num,j);
}
```

When I run the executable, it always print `0`, however, the author of the tutorial says that it return  numbers garbage value. I've googled about this and I've read that this is right, except for static variables. So it should return a garbage number instead of `0`.

I thought that this might be due to a different version of C, but the guide is from 2010.

Why do I always see `0`, instead of a garbage value?

Comment: Just because it prints `0`, doesn't mean that it isn't a garbage value. If that piece of memory contained `0` before, it's garbage value will be `0`. You shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the [C99 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) and the [C11 draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) say the value of an uninitialized automatic variable is indeterminate, from the draft c99 standard section `6.2.4` *Storage durations of objects* paragraph *5* says (*emphasis mine*):

> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends
>   from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in
>   any way. (Entering an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end,
>   execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the
>   object is created each time. **The initial value of the object is indeterminate.** If an
>   initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration is
>   reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate each
>   time the declaration is reached.

the draft standard defines indeterminate as:

> either an unspecified value or a trap representation

and an unspecified value is defined as:

> valid value of the relevant type where this International Standard imposes no
>   requirements on which value is chosen in any instance

so the value can be anything. It can vary with the compiler, optimization settings and it can even vary from run to run but it can not be relied and thus any program that uses a indeterminate value is invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The standard says this is undefined in one of the examples in section `6.5.2.5` *Compound literals* paragraph *17* which says:

> Note that if an iteration statement were used instead of an explicit goto and a labeled statement, the lifetime of the unnamed object would be the body of the loop only, and on entry next time around p would have an indeterminate value, **which would result in undefined behavior.**

this is also covered in `Annex J.2` *Undefined behavior*:

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate (6.2.4, 6.7.8, 6.8).

In some very specific cases you can make some predictions about such behavior, the presentation [Deep C](http://www.slideshare.net/olvemaudal/deep-c) goes into some of them. These types of examination should only be used as a tool to further understand how systems work and should never even come close to a production system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `j` to 1. If `j` happens to be zero, the answer will always be zero (one type of garbage). If `j` happens to non-zero, you'll get different garbage. Using uninitialized variables is undefined behaviour; 'undefined' does not exclude always being zero  in the tests you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Some systems have their memory set to 0 (Mac OS for example) so your variable will often contain 0 when you initialise it but it's a bad practice that will lead to unstable results.

Comment: Even if the system initializes memory to all zeroes, after the program has run for a while the space where the stack lives will have been overwritten with the values of several variables. Unless the stack is scrubbed, the value will persist. In OP's case, as the program is simple (one function, no other functions called before), it is probably just picking up that initial 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can't say what should happen in this case because the language specification doesn't say what should happen. In fact it says that the values of uninitialised non-static variables are indeterminate.

That means they can be any value. They can be different values on different runs of your program, or when your code is compiled on a different compiler, or when compiled on the same compiler with different optimisation settings. Or on different days of the week, national holidays or after 6pm.

An uninitialised variable can even hold what's called a trap representation, which is a value which is not valid for that type. If you access such a value then you're into the scary world of undefined behaviour where literally anything can happen.

Comment: You are in the scary world of undefined behaviour in the moment you access the unitialized variable. A machine could helpfully make your program crash (as you describe), or it could start [nethack](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetHack). Or give you 0 on weekdays, and [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)) on high holidays

Comment: @vonbrand I think that's arguable. If the uninitialized value isn't a trap representation it must be a valid value for that type, and accessing a valid value is not UB.  So on a platform that doesn't have trap representations for the type involved access an uninitialized value is safe - it must give you a valid value, just not one you can predict.

Comment: @NigelHarper I have to strongly disagree, if you read much of the work of [John Regehr](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/970) you will know the compiler can do really unexpected things with UB such as completely remove code. So this is never safe, period.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour I know that a compiler can do anything in the face of UB. The question is what, exactly, is declared to be UB with respect to uninitialized variables.

Creating an uninitialized variable is well defined. The content of that variable must either be a trap or a valid value. Accessing a trap is UB.  Accessing a valid value is well defined. 

Therefore on a platform which does not support traps, an uninitialized variable must contain a valid value and there is no UB in accessing such a value.

Comment: @NigelHarper, getting *any value whatsoever* is clearly "undefined"

Comment: @vonbrand No, it's "unspecified" which in standard land is very different. You must get a valid value, you just can't predict what it is - no crashing or launching nethack! That is very different from undefined behaviour where literally anything can happen.

Comment: It is undefined, I added the quotes to my answer, cc @vonbrand