# Why does this code work in Dev-C++ but not in Visual C++?

Tags: c, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int f,c;
int lower,upper,step;

lower = 0;
upper = 300;
step = 20;


while (f <= upper) {

    c = 5 * (f - 32) / 9;
    printf("%d\t%d\n",f,c);
    f = f + step;
}

return 0;

}
```

I forgot to write `f = lower`, but it also runs and gets the right answer. I can't post images. I think it's wrong because it won't run with Visual C++, but why?

Comment: What is your question? Are you asking why it works even though you forgot to add a line initializing the variable f?

Comment: Using an [indeterminate value is undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22416319/1708801) it seems like in your case it is initialized to zero but once you invoke undefined behavior the result is unpredictable.

Comment: yes,i think it's worng.  I am learning K&R.

Comment: In your while statement, f is not defined.

Comment: Is this working in Dev-C++ and not in Visual C++ or the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use:

```
int lower,upper,step;
```

the standard doesn't guarantee that the variables be initialized to `0` but some compilers do. If I recall correctly, Visual Studio initializes function local variables to `0` in debug build but not in release build.

The line

```
while (f <= upper) {
```

is not guaranteed to behave in a predictable way since `f` is not explicitly initialized in your program.

Comment: VS2010 warns f is not be  initialized.

Comment: @user3150832, that can be easily disabled by different compiler settings.

Comment: @user3150832 well, because it really isn't initialized, initialize it with 0 or something, don't run it like this just because one compiler will initialize the value with something, because others won't.The code you wrote is Undefined Behaviour.