# Use of INT_MAX macro and unitialized value in C

Tags: c

Why does this code not produce a compile time error? INT_MAX is a macro that holds the maximum value that can be stored in an int, but minVal is not declared and produces the value of 0 when I print it. I'm compiling with c99.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int max = INT_MAX, minVal;
    printf("Value of max: %d", max);
    printf("Value of minVal: %d", minVal);

    // Output
    // 2147483647
    // 0

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ' minVal is not declared'?

Comment: It is declared to be of int type, holding something

Comment: `minVal` is declared along with `max` ...  when you don't initialize an automatic variable the value is indeterminate and [using an indeterminate value is undefined bahavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22416319/1708801).

Comment: My confusion is why this would not result in a compile time error, but if we had done int max = maxVal; or something, then it would clearly produce an error.

Comment: Which compiler?  If it's gcc, then have you got the `-Wall` option in your command line?

Comment: @self there is no default value to an automatic variable, please see the linked question in my previous comment.

Comment: @Tony I compiled in c99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program `minVal` is declared and defined but is never initialized.

Your program invokes undefined behavior by accessing the uninitialized object `minVal` in `printf` function call.

C does not require a diagnostic or a translation error from the compiler when a program is known to invoke undefined behavior. The compiler is allowed to output a diagnostic or to stop translation (among other things) but is not required to.

Answer (score 1):

An automatic variable, which `minVal` is here, is not required to be initialized to anything by the compiler.

The safe option is to initialize it.

If you want the compiler to warn you when you don't, you can probably set a command line option.  In gcc, `-Wall` will do the job, although `-Wunitialized` will do it more specifically. (The C99 you refer to is probably, as far as I can tell, but not definitely, a wrapper for gcc).

Answer (score 0):

You declared minVal as a local int variable, and in this case you are reading 0 from it because was its initial value, but be aware that every local variable will not always be zero if you don't initialize it explicit to zero ( = 0 at variable declaration), as the standard does not require it to be zero (local variables are allocated in stack so have a undefined initial value because of the previous usage of the stack region)
only globals have a default zero as initial value