# Variable and constant with same name

Tags: c++, c

I have a C code snippet as follows:

```
const int x = 5;
void main()
{
    int x[x];
    int y = sizeof(x) / sizeof(int);
    printf("%d",y);
}
```

The code snippet would be compiled and run correctly. But I don't understand how to differentiate x 'variable' and x 'const'.

Comment: Why don't you save yourself some grief and use different, and meaningful,  identifiers? The standard dictates what should happen if two of the same name are within scope.

Comment: It's not the problem in coding style, just a question to strengthen my knowledge :)

Comment: There is no syntax in C that allows you to access the `const int x`, after declaring `x[]` in `main`. The declaration of `x[]` hides the `const int x` as long as `x[]` is in scope, which would be all of `main` in this example.

Comment: Please note `int main` is standard not `void main`.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: Specifically `int main(void)` in C, or `int main()` in C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For C++ this is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) section `3.3.2` *Point of declaration*:

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately after its complete
>   declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any), except as
>   noted below. [ Example:
>
> ```
> int x = 12;
> { int x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.
>   —end example ]

and:

> [ Note: a name from an outer scope remains visible up to the point of
>   declaration of the name that hides it.[ Example:
>
> ```
> const int i = 2;
> { int i[i]; }
> ```
>
> declares a block-scope array of two integers. —end example ] —end note
>   ]

So in your case:

```
int x[x];
```

The *const int* `x` is visible until the closing `]`. To refer to *const int* `x` after that point you can use a [qualified identifer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers):

```
::x
```

Of course this begs the question, why not just use different names and not have to deal with these edge cases?

**C**

The equivalent quotes form the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) would be from section `6.2.1` *Scopes of identifiers* (*emphasis mine*):

> Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just
>   after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the
>   tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the
>   appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. **Any
>   other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of
>   its declarator.**

and:

> [...] Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity
>   declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is
>   hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.

there is no way to make the `x` in the outer scope visible in C.

Comment: so, let say I define a variable like this: int x = x; after that, when I use y = x; what would be x here?

Comment: @duong_dajgja that would be undefined behavior since the value of `x` is indeterminate in that case: see [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) ... It is also [undefined behavior in C as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22416319/1708801)