# How local variable hides global variable

Tags: c++, c++11

What is the value of y at the end of main?

```
const int x = 5;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x[x];

    int y = sizeof(x) / sizeof(int);

    return 0;
}
```

> y is 5

What is the value of the local variable x at the end of main?

```
int x = 5;
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int x = x;
    return 0;
}
```

> x is undefined

Comment: See [Does initialization entail lvalue-to-rvalue conversion? Is `int x = x;` UB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14935722/1708801) and [Has C++ standard changed with respect to the use of indeterminate values and undefined behavior in C++14?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801)

Comment: Also see [Variable and constant with same name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29130530/1708801)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring

```
int x[x];
```

the global `x` is used to define the size of array. The `x` in the `[]` is the global variable since the declaration of the local variable is not yet complete.

In the second case,

```
int x = x;
```

is undefined behavior since the `x` on the RHS is the same as the `x` on the LHS since the declaration of `x` is complete by the time  `x` on the RHS is encountered.

These are described in the C++11 Standard:

> **3.3.2 Point of declaration**
>
> 1 The *point of declaration* for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its initializer (if any), except as noted below. [ *Example:*
>
> int x = 12;
>      { int x = x; }
>
> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value. — *end example* ]
>
> 2 *Note:* a name from an outer scope remains visible up to the point of declaration of the name that hides it.[ *Example:*
>
> ```
> const int i = 2;  
> { int i[i]; }
> ```
>
> declares a block-scope array of two integers. — *end example* ] — *end note* ]