# Why does array of uninitialized struct getting values from another array?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

When I have trying array encapsulation with struct, I got strange output from my code.
In following snippet, struct member `data[]` array getting same values from another array in main function without initialized. Why did this happen?

```
typedef struct {
  int length;
  int data[];
} Array;

int main() {
  int arr[] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

  Array myArray;
  printf("%d ", myArray.data[0]);
  printf("%d ", myArray.data[1]);
  printf("%d ", myArray.data[2]);
  return 0;
}
```

`Output : 11 12 13`

Comment: I think indexing `myArray.data[x]` is just undefined behavior,

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418166/11261546) theres' a good explanation.

Comment: `myArray.data[0]` is not part of that struct. You just illegally access whatever memory is next to your variable.

Comment: That duplicate does not match. The issue here is not about unitialized variables but actually an out of bounds access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a misconception in your question.
You assume, your struct members `data[x]` are uninitialized.
That is not the whole truth.
In fact, these do not even exist in your variable.

You have a struct with a flexible array element as last member.
This does not take any amount of memory if you create a variable of that struct type.

That means, `myArray.data[0]` is an illegal out of bounds access touching the memory next to your struct variable.
That is not uninitialized memory but just the content of other array varable. If you write to that element, you will also modify content of `arr`.

You cannot have a flexible array member in a variable.
You can only have such an array member if you dynamically allocate memory for your structure:

```c
Array *pArray = malloc(offsetof(Array, data) + N*sizeof(int) );`
```

Then you have enough memory for the fixed part of the struct as well as for the flexible part.